# How to building a fetch call to pass value to a method that expects an Object?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I currently not sure how to use a fetch post call to pass an object to a method expecting that object. I created a payload and passed it but does not seem to work. I have set a breakpoint in the code behind but it is never hit. Not sure why the fetch call is not working. Any suggestions on way the endpoint is not being reached?

This is my method in C#.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ResetPassword")]
    private void ResetPassword(Player player){

   {
```

Javascript:

```
const continueBtn = document.getElementById("continueBtn");
continueBtn.onclick = () => {
const email = document.getElementById("lblEmail").innerHTML;
sendResetEmail(email);
}

async function sendResetEmail(email) {
const payload = {
    email: email
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append("json", JSON.stringify(payload));

let sendResetEmail = await fetch(`/ResetPassword`,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    });
}
```

Comment: You would need to test for your `json` POST variable and decode it, if done like that. Perhaps you really want to get rid of `payload` and do like `const data = new FormData; data.append('email', email);`, then test for `email` and you've got what you want.

Comment: You are mixing JSON and Form encoding. Just set `body` to `JSON.stringify(payload)` and set Content-Type header to 'application/json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to provide the name of the parameter in your client, you need to give the [FromBody] attribute in your API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ResetPassword")]
private void ResetPassword([FromBody] Player player){
}
```

Then, on the client, there are multiple ways, but the most common/modern is to use JSON encoding:

```
const payload = {
    email: email
}

const data = JSON.stringify(payload);

let sendResetEmail = await fetch(`/ResetPassword`,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data
    });
}
```